# Canonical bundle relation of a curve and a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth curve lying on a smooth projective surface $X$. Let $K_C, K_X$ be their respective canonical bundle. Is it necessarily true that $h^i(C, K_X|_C)=h^i(X, K_X)$ for all $i \geq 0$?

From *Harthsorne, Chapter $3$, lemma $2.10$*, it can be noted that if $j : C \to X$ is the inclusion, then one has $h^i(C, K_X|_C)= h^i(X, j_{*}(K_X|_C))$ for all $i \geq 0$, where $j_{*}$ be the extension by zero outside $C$.

Is it elementary to see that $ j_{*}(K_X|_C)= K_X$? or do we need some extra hypothesis on $X$ or $C$ to realize this?

Comment: $j_*(K_X|_C)=K_X$ cannot be true because the left hand size has zero stalk outside of $C$ while the right hand side is a line bundle.

Comment: @KReiser, But can we say anything about the conclusion : $h^i(C, K_X|_C)= h^i(X, K_X)$ at least for $i=0$ (and for all $i \geq 0$ under certain conditions on $C$ and $X$?)

Comment: @KReiser, for example let us consider the sequence $0 \to \mathcal O_X(-C) \to \mathcal O_X \to j_{*}(\mathcal O_C) \to 0$, where the last term is pushforward. If we tensor it with $K_X$ and if it turns out that $h^i(\mathcal O_X(-C) \otimes K_X)=0$ for $i=0,1$, then  we can we use projection formula to say that $H^0(X, K_X)=H^0(X,  j_{*}(\mathcal O_C) \otimes K_X)=H^0(C, K_X|_{C})$?

Comment: Did you try to compute any example? For instance, take $X$ to be the projective plane and $C$ a line on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your general question is no. For any smooth projective surface $X$, $h^2(X,K_X)=1$ by Serre duality. But all sheaves of abelian groups on $C$ have vanishing $H^2$ by Grothendieck vanishing. There are other counterexamples with $h^1$ as well.

Comment: You mean, all coherent sheaves have $H^2 = 0$ (the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$, of course, has nonzero $H^2$).

Comment: @KReiser, I am very sorry, I should have only asked for $H^0$ and $H^1$. The special situation that I had in mind is a smooth surface of degree $d \geq 5$ in $\mathbb P^3$ and $C$ is a smooth hyperplane section of it. In that case I was trying to see whether $h^0, h^1$ coincides.

Comment: @Sasha really? Isn't Grothendieck's vanishing theorem for all sheaves of abelian groups? At least that's how it's phrased in [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02UZ) and how I remember learning the theorem many moons ago...

Comment: @Proj if you've realized that you want something different, it may be appropriate to ask a followup question. (Please keep in mind if you do decide to ask another question, you'll need to demonstrate what you've tried and what you've learned here - so for instance you'll need to address Sasha's example from the comments and the like.)

Comment: @Sasha, for projective plane $h^0(X, K_X)=0$ as $K_X \cong \mathcal O(-3)$. Again by the short exact sequence I have $0=H^0(\mathbb P^2, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(-3)) =H^0(\mathbb P^2, j_{*}(\mathcal O_l) \otimes \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(-3))$. But by projection formula can we say that the later term is same as $H^0(l, K_{\mathbb P^2}|_{l})$? For $H^1$, they are not the same, there is an inequality (please correct me if this is wrong)

Comment: @KReiser: the result, of course, depends on the topology, and we had different topologies in mind.